# Toggling display of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links, one with id #calendar_arrival_open and another with #calendar_departure_open.  Both links control whether or not a div containing a calendar is displayed, but in both cases the calendar displayed is the same calendar, to avoid loading two identical calendars. I'm trying to use the following code to toggle the opening and closing of the calendar when the links are clicked.

```
var state = "closed";
if(state == "closed"){
    $("#calendar_arrival_open").click(function () {
        $("#calendar_box").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").show();
        $("#select_departure_date").hide();
        state = "arrival_open";
    });
    $("#calendar_departure_open").click(function () {
        $("#calendar_box").show();
        $("#select_departure_date").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
        state = "departure_open";
    });
}

if(state == "arrival_open"){
    $("#calendar_arrival_open").click(function () {
        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        state = "closed";
    });
    $("#calendar_departure_open").click(function () {
        $("#select_departure_date").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
        state = "departure_open";
    });
}

if(state == "departure_open"){
    $("#calendar_arrival_open").click(function () {
        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        $("#select_departure_date").hide();
        $("#select_arrival_date").show();
        state = "arrival_open";
    });
    $("#calendar_departure_open").click(function () {
        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        state = "closed";
    });
}
```

This code works for opening the calendar, but not for closing it. I can't see why. As you can see, if the "arrival calendar" is open and the departure calendar link is clicked, the "departure calendar" appears, and vice-versa.  However, if the arrival calendar is open and the arrival calendar link is clicked, then the calendar closes.

Can anyone see the problem? Is this "state" method the best for handling what I need?

Comment: Your `if` statements should be inside the event handlers, not outside!

Comment: This is because the javascript is interpreted by the browser only once, ie, never it is interpreted as the 'state! = "closed"'. You need put this inside of event handlers.

Comment: Need a little more scope on this. This code rewrites the onclick methods for these links, it doesn't actually execute anything until a click happens. When is this code being executed? When the document loads, or each time a click happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var state = "closed";

$("#calendar_arrival_open").click(function () {
    if(state == "closed"){

        $("#calendar_box").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").show();
        $("#select_departure_date").hide();
        state = "arrival_open";

    } else if(state == "arrival_open"){

        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        state = "closed";

    } else {

        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        $("#select_departure_date").hide();
        $("#select_arrival_date").show();
        state = "arrival_open";

    }
});

$("#calendar_departure_open").click(function () {
    if(state == "closed"){

        $("#calendar_box").show();
        $("#select_departure_date").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
        state = "departure_open";

    } else if(state == "arrival_open"){

        $("#select_departure_date").show();
        $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
        state = "departure_open";

    } else {

        $("#calendar_box").hide();
        state = "closed";

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that runs when a click event occurs must be defined inside a `click` event handler. On your code, you want the state check to be performed on every click, but you added the `if` statement outside the event handlers. Then you are stuck with those handlers from your first `if` block.

Your code says: "when `state` is `x`, define a `click` event handler to do `a`; when `state` is `y`, define a `click` event handler to do `b`;".

What you want is: "when an element is clicked, do `a` if `state`is `x`, or `b` if `state` is `y`".

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch block to achieve this. I'm not sure if that's quicker programatically, but it looks easier to maintain to me.

This obviously needs to be placed inside a `$(document).ready()` handler.

```
var state = "closed";

$("#calendar_arrival_open").click(function () {

switch(state){

case "closed":
    $("#calendar_box").show();
    $("#select_arrival_date").show();
    $("#select_departure_date").hide();
    state = "arrival_open"; 
break;
case "arrival_open":
    $("#calendar_box").hide();
    state = "closed";   
break;  
case "departure_open":
    $("#calendar_box").hide();
    $("#select_departure_date").hide();
    $("#select_arrival_date").show();
    state = "arrival_open";
break;  
}
})

$("#calendar_departure_open").click(function () {

switch(state){

case "closed":
    $("#calendar_box").show();
    $("#select_departure_date").show();
    $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
    state = "departure_open";
break;
case "arrival_open":
    $("#select_departure_date").show();
    $("#select_arrival_date").hide();
    state = "departure_open";
break;  
case "departure_open":
    $("#calendar_box").hide();
    state = "closed";
break;  
}
})
```

Comment: If/when someone experienced reads this, could they confirm that it's a suitable solution? I'm new to this, so it'd be good to make sure! Thanks :-)